# No such file or directory while reading csv file with pandas in anaconda cloud

Tags: pandas, load

Can someone help me understand why i am getting the error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pandas_course/Project_data/project_transactions.csv'?

From the images you can see that the file is present in the directory

[Code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ilXH.png)
[Directory screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ZDt.png)

I am expecting to load the csv file

Comment: When I looked at your directory image, I saw **a forward slash (/) at the beginning**.

Comment: You are not giving the complete path. The `Project_pandas` must be in some folder. Add the path of that as well.